# Is there an IDE I can code Python which will produce an android (Dalvik byte code) app

Tags: android, python

As the Android team chose to base Dalvik on Java byte code instead of Java source code. This means that you could write Android applications in another language that compiles down to Java byte code.

For example, you could use Python to code your Android app.

Has anyone found and used a frameworks or IDE that supports Python and can be used for Android development? I'm not looking for an opinion about such an IDE just a link to the website where I can download and try out the IDE myself.

So far I have found
[a presentation](https://ep2013.europython.eu/conference/talks/developing-android-apps-completely-in-python)

Comment: Try Eclipse. might help you

Comment: I think what you want is a compiler. Maybe check this out: https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/GeneralInfo

Comment: Thank you for the compiler link.On that page it asks "Can I use Jython to make apps for mobile phones?" and answers "Unfortunately not." What I would like is an IDE or Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has already created what you are looking for. Its called [SL4A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_Layer_for_Android) and its public repo is [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/). This allows you to write and execute programs written in Python directly on any Android device. Other scripting languages are also supported.

Here are some good learning guides for SL4A: [Python Central](http://www.pythoncentral.io/series/python-sl4a-android-scripting-layer-tutorial/), [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-python-sl4a-1/) and [Google](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/Tutorials). You can also get [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430235691) book.

Apart from SL4A, there are two other options that you can evaluate: [Kivy](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/android.html) and [QPython](http://qpython.com/). Hope this helps ... :)

Comment: Yes, this is a very helpful. answer, thank you, especially the link for the book. I wonder if anyone other than Google has attempted this.

Comment: Thanks for all the info on SL4A, it lead me to http://clusterbleep.net/blog/2012/07/31/how-to-create-an-android-app-and-apk-on-android-with-python/

Comment: Thanks for all the info on SL4A, it lead me to: http://clusterbleep.net/blog/2012/07/31/how-to-create-an-android-app-and-apk-on-android-with-python/ This is the type of solution I was looking for, however, are there other alternative answers to this question, i.e. are there IDEs which allow creation of android app using python?

Comment: The clusterbleep blog entry looks fascinating, I'm just wondering if there is a solution out there that works straight out of the box.

Comment: Thank you again ZygoteInit and now studying your edited response above about Kivy and QPthon to see if they answer my question..

Comment: Please see the edited answer ... and also thanks for the clusterbleep link!

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to asking questions here. The discussions I've read before on this forum looked extended. I need to read up on the difference between discussion and chat.

Comment: No problem ... everyone learns with experience!